# List.RemoveAll not working when matching against another list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to edit a list of network data down to a CSV file, which means I need to trim out some of the headers, etc. I made an array of strings I'd like to remove but it's not working as I'd like.
Here's my code:

```
string[] unwanted = new[] { "-","Mac", "Address", "Table", "Vlan", "Type", "Ports" };
var textList = text.Split(' ').ToList();
textList.RemoveAll(x => unwanted.Contains(x));

foreach(string line in textList)
{
 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
 {
     writeFile(line+",");
 }
}
```

The output I see has "Mac" and "Address" removed, but none of the others. Example:

"Table,-------------------------------------------

Vlan,Ports
----,-----------,--------,-----"

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: What is in `text`?  Why are you splitting on spaces in a CSV?

Comment: I'm trying to create a CSV, splitting on spaces is intentional.

Comment: What is in `text`?

Comment: @Netmage - It's the results of a show mac address-table CLI command on a Cisco 3650 switch. The example I included above is basically all the unwanted text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting your source data on the space character, but not on the newline character, so you have words such as "Table\n-----" which don't match anything. You need to use Regex to find the words to remove, I suggest:

```
string[] unwanted = new[] { "Mac", "Address", "Table", "Vlan", "Type", "Ports" };

textList.RemoveAll(x => unwanted.Any(us => Regex.IsMatch(x, $@"\b{us}\b", RegexOptions.Multiline)));
textList.RemoveAll(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, @"-+|^$", RegexOptions.Multiline));
```

Also, the single `-` won't match anything, so I added a line to remove the hyphen words and the empty words.

Comment: I am doing similar Cisco stuff with a Perl CLI replacement I wrote to manage my 3750-X switches.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for "-------------------------------------------" in ["-", "Mac", ...] which doesn't exist so it doesn't get removed.

Since you're calling Split with ' ' you aren't getting any individual dashes back.

I think you need to handle the dashes separately, something like:

`text = text.Replace("-", string.Empty);`

Edit - Put a breakpoint at `textList.RemoveAll` and look at the contents of textList. You'll see that the lines that aren't being removed are ones that don't match anything in unwanted.

Comment: This wasn't the fix but the breakpoint idea did get me thinking in the right direction so I gave your answer an upvote. I think I'll have this fixed today and I'll post the solution unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: ... and someone beat me to it. NetMage nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

can this be a case sensitivity problem:
try this:

```
textList.RemoveAll(x => unwanted.Contains(x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: I did test if it was a case sensitivity issue but it's not. Thank you, though!